# Stacked grid-layout on small screens to carousel on large screens

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel

I've got a layout that's basically like this:
[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7P4o.png)

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and I'm wondering if there's a way to create this using Bootstrap elements? In essence: I want the cards to stack in mobile view, but on large screens they should turn into carousel view.

Updated with code.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .carousel {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .categories {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<section>
        <div id="carouselControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div class="carousel-caption"><h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Veritatis, doloremque.</h1></div>
                    <img class="d-block w-100 h-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1610949996748-1f8437b6b12f?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1651&q=80" alt="First slide">
                </div><!--carousel-item-->
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="carousel-caption"><h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Veritatis, doloremque.</h1></div>
                    <img class="d-block w-100 h-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554151228-14d9def656e4?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NHx8aHVtYW58ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="Second slide">
                </div><!--carousel-item-->
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="carousel-caption"><h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Veritatis, doloremque.</h1></div>
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554151228-14d9def656e4?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NHx8aHVtYW58ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="Third slide">
                </div><!--carousel-item-->
            </div><!--carouse-inner-->
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div> <!--carousel-->
    </section>

      <!-- SMALL SCREEN STACKED -->
    <section>
        <div class="categories">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="row category" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1610949996748-1f8437b6b12f?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1651&q=80);">
                    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"><h1>Category 2</h1></div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <div class="row category" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554151228-14d9def656e4?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NHx8aHVtYW58ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60)">
                    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"><h1>Category 2</h1></div>
                </div>
            </a>

            <a href="#">
                <div class="row category" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1515634928627-2a4e0dae3ddf?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2100&q=80);">
                    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"><h1>Category 2</h1></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
      
    </section>
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Any code you can share with us?

Comment: I just added what I've created so far... I feel like this is cheating and there should be a more elegant way to do this but can't figure it out...

Comment: In this moment you have a working solution, but not elegant, don't you? But for me is correct because you have 2 different things, a carousel and a scrollable stack. Or do you want a vertical carousel?

Comment: Googling https://www.codeply.com/go/PgxKT3h6x6/bootstrap-4-vertical-slider